# How to configure WCF REST to work with SSL?

Tags: wcf, rest, ssl

I have a nice WCF REST-ful JSON service working well as is. The problem arises when I try to put it to work on HTTPS. The Web.config is as follows:

```
 <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <webHttpBinding>
        <binding name="StreamedRequestWebBinding" bypassProxyOnLocal="true" useDefaultWebProxy="false" hostNameComparisonMode="WeakWildcard" sendTimeout="10:15:00" openTimeout="10:15:00" receiveTimeout="10:15:00" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" transferMode="StreamedRequest">
          <security mode="Transport">
            <transport clientCredentialType = "None"  />
          </security>
          <readerQuotas maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" />
        </binding>
      </webHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <services>
      <service name="WcfRESTFullJSON.Service1" behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehaviour">
        <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="StreamedRequestWebBinding" contract="WcfRESTFullJSON.IService1" />
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpsBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="ServiceBehaviour">
          <serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="web">
          <!--Him-->
          <webHttp automaticFormatSelectionEnabled="true" />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
```

I configured a home-made certificate on IIS.
On the client I have:

```
WebClient WC;
...
WC.UploadData(URL, "POST", asciiBytes);
```

What we get:

```
The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error.
```

What may be the problem?

Comment: Do you have any sort of logging in your service?  You can also [enable WCF tracing](http://utilicode.wordpress.com/2012/04/23/enable-wcf-tracing/) to see what's going on.

Comment: System.ServiceModel.FaultException: The message ... cannot be processed at the receiver, due to an AddressFilter mismatch at the EndpointDispatcher.  Check that the sender and receiver's EndpointAddresses agree... When 'system.serviceModel/serviceHostingEnvironment/multipleSiteBindingsEnabled' is set to true in configuration, the endpoints are required to specify a relative address. If you are specifying a relative listen URI on the endpoint, then the address can be absolute. To fix this problem, specify a relative uri for endpoint..

Comment: ... How to specify a relative address? Thank you very much.

Comment: Now the remaining error is: System.InvalidOperationException: Could not find a base address that matches scheme https for the endpoint with binding MetadataExchangeHttpsBinding. Registered base address schemes are [http].

Comment: Add a binding for https on your site in IIS.

Comment: It is added. Now I have set in web.config  multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="false" After this the error says: The message with Action '' cannot be processed at the receiver, due to a ContractFilter mismatch at the EndpointDispatcher. This may be because of either a contract mismatch (mismatched Actions between sender and receiver) or a binding/security mismatch between the sender and the receiver.  Check that sender and receiver have the same contract and the same binding (including security requirements, e.g. Message, Transport, None)

Comment: Looks like the message is coming in with a blank Action.  Not sure if that's usual in REST or not, since I haven't worked with REST, but look into that.

Comment: I configured a Service client the normal way and wrote the same configuration in app.config. The result is the same. Shall try with Action too.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is resolved. It was a missing reference to a endpoint behavior in the following line
...endpoint  **behaviorConfiguration="web"** address="" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="StreamedRequestWebBinding" contract="WcfRESTFullJSON.IService1"...
in the Web.config below. Thank you for your help friends! The solution was finally found in the article [Implementing 5 important principles of REST using WCF Services](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/283550/Implementing-5-important-principles-of-REST-using#h)

```
    <services>
  <service name="WcfRESTFullJSON.Service1" behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehaviour">
    <endpoint  behaviorConfiguration="web" address="" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="StreamedRequestWebBinding" contract="WcfRESTFullJSON.IService1" />
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpsBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
  </service>
</services>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="ServiceBehaviour">
      <serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="web">
      <!--Him-->
      <webHttp automaticFormatSelectionEnabled="true" />
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
```

Answer (score 0):

As SSL is a protocol under HTTP, there is usually nothing extra to configure in web.config (only a new binding). Another thing that changes if you use SSL is the port... you may need to update the firewall or check that your request is sent to the right port.

Comment: The request is sent to the right port (443). Verified in Fiddler. Turning the Firewall off changes nothing.

Comment: When I try to debug in Visual Studio by using IIS, I get the message: "Unable to start debugging on the web server. The web server is not configured correctly. See help for common configuration errors..." I configured on 2 machines and the behavior is the same.

Answer (score 0):

```
 See Complete config file
<configuration>   <system.web>
        <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
        <webServices>
          <protocols>
            <add name="HttpsGet"/>
            <add name="HttpsPost"/>
          </protocols>
        </webServices>   </system.web>   <system.serviceModel>
        <services>
          <service  name="RESTTEST.RestTestService" behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehavior">

            <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" 
                      contract="RESTTEST.IRestTestService" 
                      bindingConfiguration="sslBinding"
                      behaviorConfiguration="web"
                      ></endpoint>
            <endpoint address="mex"
                  binding="mexHttpsBinding"
                  contract="IMetadataExchange" />
          </service>
        </services>
        <behaviors>
          <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior name="ServiceBehavior">
              <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before
    deployment -->
              <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
              <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before
    deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
              <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
            </behavior>
          </serviceBehaviors>
          <endpointBehaviors>
            <behavior name="web">
              <webHttp/>
            </behavior>
          </endpointBehaviors>
        </behaviors>
        <bindings>
          <webHttpBinding>
            <binding name="sslBinding" crossDomainScriptAccessEnabled="true">
              <security mode="Transport">
              </security>
            </binding>
          </webHttpBinding>    
          </bindings>
        <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="false">
        </serviceHostingEnvironment>
        <standardEndpoints>
          <webHttpEndpoint>
            <standardEndpoint crossDomainScriptAccessEnabled="true"></standardEndpoint>
          </webHttpEndpoint>
          <webScriptEndpoint>
            <standardEndpoint name="" crossDomainScriptAccessEnabled="true" />
          </webScriptEndpoint>
        </standardEndpoints>   </system.serviceModel>   <system.webServer>
        <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
        <httpProtocol>
          <customHeaders>
            <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
            <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type" />
          </customHeaders>
        </httpProtocol>   </system.webServer> </configuration>
```